# Typescript: How do you filter a type's properties to those of a certain type?

Tags: typescript

I have a interface

```
export interface MyInterface {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: number;
}
```

I want to create a literal type of the property names for which value is of type number

I know how to get the type with all property names using

```
type MyType = keyof MyInterface // gives 'a'|'b'|'c'
```

I want to get just 'a'|'c'

Comment: You cannot. You would need to create a separate interface for this. You could create one interface for `a | c` and then create another one which extends it with `b`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In TypeScript how to specify only keys of a generic object whose values are strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-specify-only-keys-of-a-generic-object-whose-values-are-stri)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You certainly can define such a type in TypeScript:

```
type KeysMatching<T extends object, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type MyType = KeysMatching<MyInterface, number>;
// type MyType = "a" | "c"
```

In this, `KeysMatching<T, V>` returns the set of keys of `T` whose properties are assignable to `V`.  It uses a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) and [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type along with a property [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  For each key `K` in `keyof T`, it checks whether `T[K]` is assignable to `V`.  If so, it returns the key `K`; if not, it returns `never`.  So for your types it would be something like `{a: "a", b: never, c: "c"}`.  Then we look up the property values and get a union of the types like `"a" | never | "c"` which reduces to `"a" | "c"`, exactly as you wanted.

Do note that `KeysMatching<T, V>` only returns those property keys whose values match `V` when *reading* the property.  Those that are exactly `V` or a subtype of `V`:

```
interface AnotherInterface {
  narrower: 1;
  exact: number;
  wider: string | number;
}

type AnotherType = KeysMatching<AnotherInterface, number>;
// type AnotherType = "narrower" | "exact"
```

If you want to get the keys which match `V` when *writing* a property of `T`... that is, exactly `V` or a *supertype* of `V`, then you need a different implementation of `KeysMatching`:

```
type KeysMatchingWrite<T extends object, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: [V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type AnotherTypeWrite = KeysMatchingWrite<AnotherInterface, number>;
// type AnotherTypeWrite = "exact" | "wider"
```

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#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)

Comment: Damn! That's really amazing. I shall delete my answer for this.

Comment: Where can I learn more about that `-` in your type definition?

Comment: See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers); it’s removing any optional modifier that may be present, so as not to get `undefined` in the list of keys

Comment: I think it will also include fields of a type `never`. Maybe can be fixed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492934/2782477).

Comment: I don't see a problem that needs to be fixed; `never` is assignable to every type so they should be included with `KeysMatching` (but not `KeysMatchingWrite`).

Comment: Amazing answer! What's the difference between `[V] extends [T[K]]` and `T[K]` extends V`?

Comment: They're checking different things? If `V` is `"abc"` and `T[K]` is `string` then `[V] extends [T[K]]` is true but `T[K] extends V` is false.

Comment: Oh, sorry, what I've meant was what's the difference between `[V] extends [T[K]]` and `V extends T[K]`. That is - why did you wrap them in square brackets?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792483/2887218 and the [documentation for distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

Comment: hi there, I'm trying to go further and find a way to work with such a type in a function. please see the example:

`type TypedKeys<T extends Object, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];`

and then use it in a function:
`function getValue<T extends Object, TKey extends TypedKeys<T, number>>(t: T, key: TKey): number {
    return t[key];
}
`
Can't get it working when I try to get a value by such a key from the T object. Getting the error: `Type 'T[TKey]' is not assignable to type 'number'.`  Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: Comments sections on answers to old questions aren't great places to explore followup issues.  I'd say you should switch your constraints to `K extends keyof T, T extends Record<K, number>` instead, but if you want to discuss more you should open a new question if you can't find one that answers it exactly. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz wow that's a way different approach but it works!  thanks a lot!
btw I found as well this issue helpful  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992

Answer (score 2):

don't think you can pick properties by type but if you know the properties you accept you can create a new type based on those like this;

```js
type MyType = Pick<MyInterface, 'a' | 'c'>
```

I like [this blog post](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-built-in-generics/) that covers most of the types (`Readonly`, `Partial`, `Required`, `Pick`, `Record`, `Extract`, `Exclude` etc) you could use, but I know `Omit` has been introduced lately too.

I found this answer that explains it better; [Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) library.

`npm i utility-types`

It has a bunch of extra TypeScript utility types that make doing stuff like this much easier.

The particular utility type you would be interested in is [`PickByValueExact<ObjectType, ValueType>`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#pickbyvalueexactt-valuetype)

```
import { PickByValueExact } from 'utility-types';

type Props = { req: number; reqUndef: number | undefined; opt?: string; };

// Expect: { req: number }
type Props = PickByValueExact<Props, number>;
// Expect: { reqUndef: number | undefined; }
type Props = PickByValueExact<Props, number | undefined>;
```

There is also the more lenient [`PickByValue<ObjectType, ValueType>`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#pickbyvaluet-valuetype) utility

```
import { PickByValue } from 'utility-types';

type Props = { req: number; reqUndef: number | undefined; opt?: string; };

// Expect: { req: number }
type Props = PickByValue<Props, number>;
// Expect: { req: number; reqUndef: number | undefined; }
type Props = PickByValue<Props, number | undefined>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

```
type KeysMatching<T extends object, V> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any
}
type MyType = KeysMatching<MyInterface, number>
// MyType = 'a' | 'c'
```

If `T[K]` is not assignable to `V`, we exclude it from properties by specifying `never` type
(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756175) for detailed description.)