# typescript: How do you reduce a type's properties to those of a specific type?

Tags: typescript, types

I've got a type like this:

```
type T = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  x: number,
  y: number,
}

function fun(input: number, t: T, p: ???) {
  t[p] = input;
}
```

I want `p` to accept `'x' | 'y'`. But, if I add a new numeric property, `z`, I want it to accept `'x' | 'y' | 'z'`

**Is this possible to do?** I've been researching `keyof` and mapped types and conditionals because I feel like there should a way to use them together to remove properties by types, but I can't find a way.

Here's my stab at it:

```
function fun<K extends keyof T>(input: number, t: T, p: T[K] extends number ? K : never) {
  t[p] = input;
}
```

This doesn't compile, but I'm not sure how to get closer to what I want. It feels like there's something I don't know I don't know.

Comment: If I use `KeysMatching` from the answer to [the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863875/create-literal-type-from-keys-of-interface-filtered-by-value-type) in your example, I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mplKpm).  Hope that helps!

Comment: @jcalz awesome, thanks