# How to avoid distributive conditional types

Tags: typescript

These are the types I have:

```
type Action<T> = T extends undefined ? {
    type: string;
} : {
    type: string;
    payload: T;
}

type ApiResponse<T> = {
    ok: false;
    error: string;
} | {
    ok: true;
    data: T;
};
```

I've defined this function:

```
function handleApiResponse<T>(apiResponse: ApiResponse<T>) {
    const a: Action<ApiResponse<T>> = {
        type: "response",
        payload: apiResponse,
    }
}
```

The problem is `a` has an error because the conditional type in `Action` is distributed over `ApiResponse`.

What I need from `Action<T>` is a type that is literally what it says, i.e., there are two cases:

1. The type parameter passed to `Action<T>` is undefined, in which case `Action<undefined>` = `{ type: string }`
2. The type parameter passed to `Action<T>` is anything else, in which case `Action<T>` = `{ type: string, payload: T }`

But this doesn't work when `T` is a union type because of distributed conditional types.

How can I define a type like this that works even when `T` is a union?

Comment: In the documentation for [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) I linked yesterday, at the bottom, it says: "Typically, distributivity is the desired behavior. To avoid that behavior, you can surround each side of the `extends` keyword with square brackets."  So `[T] extends [undefined]` should do it.

Comment: @jcalz Fixed, thanks a lot. If you want to write up an answer I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you mentioned, your definition of `Action<T>` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), in which [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T` are split up into their individual members (e.g., `B | C | D`), passed through `Action<T>`, and the result put back into a new union (e.g., `Action<B> | Action<C> | Action<D>`).  This is often the behavior people want from their conditional types, but it's not what you want here; that is, you've used a distributive conditional type *accidentally*.

A conditional type  of the form `TTT extends UUU ? VVV : WWW` will only be distributive if the type `TTT` that you're checking is a bare [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type parameter* like the `T` in your definition of `Action<T>`.  If it's some specific type (like `string` or `Date`), it won't be distributive.  And if it's a more complicated expression involving a type parameter (like `{x: T}`), it won't be distributive.  I sometimes refer to this latter idea, where you take the "bare" type parameter `T` and do something to it like `{x: T}`, as "clothing" the type parameter.

---

So you've got `T extends undefined`, which is distributive:

```
type Action<T> = T extends undefined ? ... : ...
```

If you want to turn that off, you need to rephrase the check so that `T` is clothed but where it has the same behavior (so the check succeeds if and only if `T` extends `undefined`).  The easiest way to do this is to clothe both sides of the `extends` clause to be a one-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)), so `T` becomes `[T]` and `undefined` becomes `[undefined]`:

```
type Action<T> = [T] extends [undefined] ? ... : ...
```

and then your code works:

```
function handleApiResponse<T>(apiResponse: ApiResponse<T>) {
  const a: Action<ApiResponse<T>> = { 
    type: "response",
    payload: apiResponse,
  } // okay
}
```

Note that TypeScript considers tuples and arrays to be [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in their element types, meaning that `Array<X> extends Array<Y>` or `[X] extends [Y]` if and only if `X extends Y`.  This is technically unsafe to do (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60905518/2887218) and its answers for more info) but very convenient.

---

So that's a general rule you can use: if you have `TTT extends UUU ? VVV : WWW` and it's accidentally distributive, you can turn that off by writing `[TTT] extends [UUU] ? VVV : WWW`.  This is mentioned at the bottom of the [documentation for distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), although it just sort of says "do this" and not why it works.  It might look like the square brackets are some kind of special syntax designed for conditional types... but it's not.  It's just using existing one-element tuple syntax, which happens to do what we want without requiring too many more characters.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYB4AqA+KBeKAbUwF0oIAPYCVAEwGciBXOiAM0VQlrIH4oA3gFgAUFCihIALij1gAJ04BzANyiAvlBnCxE8BBlzFqVaPFgAhiAA2yC7RmY1I9aNGToMMIgBKEemBo9BBYuAQ64sgA1jJsFtbBzuIQ8vLI8oYKys6aAD6CZlDRMgpMEElQtBbAFo45zm4ibCwIKKhQABYWdNYQXr7+gajBoQAUFt5+AUEGsJODM6EAlAW6cEHAULWwrWjo-VNDIzhhglCF4h4yAETyC8MQ1wA0F1CWNnYOW-PTDy+6mgA9ICilErBpREA)