# Typescript union in optional generic not working

Tags: typescript

I have a type that takes an optional generic. If generic G provided, a new property of type G  must be included. However, I'm running into a problem when doing this in a function:

```js
interface Message {
  id: string;
  message: string;
}

interface MessageWithContext<T> extends Message {
  context: T;
};

// Optional generic. If generic provided,
// context must also provided.
type NotificationMessage<T = void> = T extends void
  ? Message
  : MessageWithContext<T>;

interface Context1 {
  status: 'GOOD';
}

interface Context2 {
  status: 'BAD';
  error: string;
}

type AllContext = Context1 | Context2;

// DOES NOT WORK. See error below.
function toMessage(context: AllContext): NotificationMessage<AllContext> {
  return {
    id: '123',
    message: 'hello world',
    context: context
  };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcxQbwChllgATALmQzClBwG5jkBbTbPKmukRwgX0KFQkWIhTosuCAHVgYABYBhAPbgIADzAAeACoA+ZJsggyGNO2nIiJBGshaqupvyaEA9O+QB5AA5hgNTgAG2Q8EGhgBAA6ZABJGDCICLoEZF8oFQA3cggyABoPLzt1LVYAVxpkEIwVdMycsjzowjAAT18UADkVAJgouAC1SQ4IPWQAXmQslXJDKd0jLWSzadmyZgB+Cyk8ZioR6TlFVVKdAzcRaHgkZFOHMABGa2YaQcqqAHIAcW9vABFPi4hFcxLd7sYAEwvEhvMAfZCfABCAEFAUwSNBMlAuLR6MDWh0UCjgsEIWUpuSnsgAD53exQtyeZD-bwAUQAysgut5FjJvAAlADSsQ5EBQWJUUGQACMIMEVAB3FowcogBBDEDIMAqQ54AAUJQeVBJZIZWgAlFQen0Bpq9WNTVTDDZkFAIPCoFrXSRyF8NJ9CiQSGxdhAvgp5QrkIqpcEyIHmLZzWAqEbjMxXAIgA).

The error that I'm getting:

```
Type '{ id: string; message: string; context: AllContext; }' is not assignable to type 'MessageWithContext<Context1> | MessageWithContext<Context2>'.
  Type '{ id: string; message: string; context: AllContext; }' is not assignable to type 'MessageWithContext<Context2>'.
    Types of property 'context' are incompatible.
      Type 'AllContext' is not assignable to type 'Context2'.
        Property 'error' is missing in type 'Context1' but required in type 'Context2'.(2322)
```

Comment: Your playground link and code here does not result in the error you are showing. Did you forget an `id` property? It's helpful to have a true [mre] so that people can immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wybabw) meet your needs? Unless you intend `NotificationMessage<T>` to be [distributive over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in `T`, then you don't need a distributive conditional type, and things will start working for you when you change it to a regular conditional type.

Comment: (Please edit the plaintext code as well, not just the playground link)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! I did fix both the link and the plaintext. And YES that does fix it! Thank you! Why does putting square brackets make it non-distributive? The link provided doesn't go into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition of `NotificationMessage`:

```
type NotificationMessage<T = void> = T extends void
  ? Message
  : MessageWithContext<T>;
```

is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), because the type `T` that you're checking is a generic type parameter.  Distributive conditional types  *distribute* the type operation over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in the relevant type argument, so that `NotificationMessage<A | B | C>` will be evaluated as `NotificationMessage<A> | NotificationMessage<B> | NotificationMessage<C>`:

```
type M = NotificationMessage<AllContext>
// type M = MessageWithContext<Context1> | 
//   MessageWithContext<Context2>
```

Which means `NotificationMessage<AllContext>` is itself a union type.  And while the value `{ id: '123', message: 'hello world', context: context }` *could* be considered assignable to such a union type, the compiler doesn't make any attempt to verify this.  It only [tries to do this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) if the target type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and `NotificationMessage<AllContext>` is not one (it has no discriminant property... no, subproperties don't count, see [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758)).  So there's an error.

If you really wanted `NotificationMessage<AllContext>` to itself be a union type, we could look at how to fix up `toMessage()` to allow it to work.  But you don't seem to actually be trying to do this.  You'd presumably be happy if `NotificationMessage<AllContext>` were a single object type with a union-typed `context` property.

That means you don't want `NotificationMessage<T>` to be distributive in `T`.  The easiest way to "shut off" distributivity is to wrap each side of the `T extends U` condition in square brackets to make one-element [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

```
type NotificationMessage<T = void> = [T] extends [void]
  ? Message
  : MessageWithContext<T>;
```

See [this Stack Overflow Q/A about avoiding distributivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792483/2887218) for more information about why this works.  Now you've got a non-distributive type:

```
type M = NotificationMessage<AllContext>
// type M = MessageWithContext<AllContext>
```

And now everything just works:

```
function toMessage(context: AllContext): NotificationMessage<AllContext> {
  return {
    id: '123',
    message: 'hello world',
    context: context
  }; // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=30&ssc=34&pln=29&pc=44#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-pUBoAFCU3lQxQyAJRUPnAfoIQaBIWWEXpk2GGzIKAQVFQEBIkikSjo97wgDM-0KDdYxYgAPl1LqMpUUGCZA7zFsJqoKeMzFcyD9KgA1nA2gIgA)