# how to filter keys by functions that aren't promises?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a type that filters an object by keys that values that are functions, but are not promise functions.

How can I make sure `type keys` only returns "A", because B returns a Promise and therefore should be excluded?

```
type FilterKeys<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type O = {
  A: () => void;
  B: () => Promise<void>;
};

// type keys = "A" | "B"
// WANT: type keys = "A"
type keys = FilterKeys<O, (e: never) => void>;

// type keys2 = "B"
// OK
type keys2 = FilterKeys<O, (e: never) => Promise<void>>;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: How do you filter a type's properties to those of a certain type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863875/typescript-how-do-you-filter-a-types-properties-to-those-of-a-certain-type)

Comment: it doesn't address my specific question

Comment: So you're not really asking about filtering keys, but why `() => Promise<void>` is assignable to `() => void`, right?  If so then it's because *all* zero-arg functions are assignable to `() => void`, as described [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void).  If you're trying to ask how to distinguish `() => void` from `() => Promise<void>`, that makes sense, but it really has very little to do with filtering keys. Could you [edit] the question so that you explicitly ask about distinguishing function types and not about keys?

Comment: A `void` return type really means _"don't rely on this value"_; _any_ function, irrespective of return type, can be be used if the caller doesn't care about what it returns.

Comment: @jcalz: the goal is still to write the necessary type to do the filtering

Comment: [Why are functions returning non-`void` assignable to function returning `void`?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: ok, i understand void means "don't rely on this value" 

Given that, how to i write a filter function that returns type keys = "A"?

Comment: ① I maintain that "filtering keys" is not your problem and it will lead to people pointing you to answers you don't want. But it's up to you how to phrase the question, I guess. ② You can do the void-return check [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mAaQZm), although it depends on the use cases (because you're fighting against the type system by doing it, you might have different expectations than that filtering function). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - I think that does answer the question, yes.  but since it's 'fighting the type system", Perhaps  the constraint can be relaxed to just be "something that isn't a promise" to select "A", instead of explicitly void.

Comment: That's up to you... but note that you didn't phrase the question that way ("not `Promise`" vs "exactly `void`"). Do you want to [edit] to change it? Or do you think you can take it from here if I answer the question as it's currently asked?

Comment: Okay, now you just need to reverse the sense of your filtering to `Exclude` instead of `Extract`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpoL7N). Does that fully address the new version of this question? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: yes, thankyou - this fully answers the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FilterKeys<T, U>` behaves like [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) in that it selects things that are assignable to another type.  You can get the behavior you want by selecting things that are *not* assignable to another type, making it behave like [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) instead.  Simply switch the true and false branches of the relevant [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type ExcludeKeys<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? never : K;
}[keyof T];
```

Then you can use `ExcludeKeys` with `() => Promise<unknown>` to get just the keys whose values are not `Promise`-returning functions:

```
type O = {
  A: () => void;
  B: () => Promise<string>;
};

type Keys = ExcludeKeys<O, () => Promise<unknown>>;
//   ^? type Keys = "A"
```

Note that `() => Promise<unknown>` is wider than `() => Promise<void>`, and will therefore catch all `Promise`-returning functions.

---

Of course this will also give you non-functions, so if you need to keep *only* keys whose value types are functions that don't return promises, you'll need a combination of your two filters:

```
type ExtractKeys<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
    
type O = {
  A: () => void;
  B: () => Promise<void>;
  C: string // we don't want this one either
};

type Keys = ExcludeKeys<Pick<O, ExtractKeys<O, Function>>, () => Promise<unknown>>;
//   ^? type Keys = "A"
```

Or you could build a combination filter:

```
type ExtractExcludeKeys<T, Y, N> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends N ? never : T[K] extends Y ? K : never;
}[keyof T]

type Keys = ExtractExcludeKeys<O, Function, () => Promise<unknown>>;
//   ^? type Keys = "A"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDSEQGcA8AKgDRQCqAfFALxQDeAUFFANqZQCWAdlANY4B7AGZRCAXQBcotmKgQ4wCFzS5yUAPxQuEAG4QATlCmYA3AwC+LfiGGixZhqEiwF+gIYJg2PEVKUa9Eys7Nx8giLiUoQycgpKKmqa7FLaevpmlta24g6O4NAA8gGMzACCUgAUAJQ0VDoCHGhmzABClTXUVAAK+gIAthy4EPi4wPrcAOYUzVAAwlKj41wTFg5O0N6qtPDI6Fg4BF0cCLz4BaTwYx5eB2ekAGIoXJ4cAlwUFKTVtVA9-YPDJ68LgCADu72mDAA9FDmFAAHrqBh5ZyXdyeHaoDCbXxQACapAAclRaCVgpweFkIpJpJhZPJFMpVISNFpdAYjLT6XEmfjWck2WkMlZwnZkesoJsAEwBNHXTF7HHnKCPZ7AV5cL4dbq9AZDfBAkHgj5mGFwxFAA)