# filter properties based on property type

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there someway to construct a type based on a generic type, where i extract all properties of a specific type?

```js
class Test {
  value1!: Date
  value2!: number
  value3!: Date
  value4!: string
}
type FilterProperties<T, TFieldType> = //some magic here where we only pick fields that have the type TFieldType
const onlyDates = {} as FilterProperties<Test, Date>
```

`FilterProperties<Test, Date>` should only have the properties `value1` and `value3` when this works as expected.

I tried to get this to work with `Extract` and `Pick` but they both work on a key basis instead of type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: pick properties with a defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583883/typescript-pick-properties-with-a-defined-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method:

```ts
class Test {
  value1!: Date
  value2!: number
  value3!: Date
  value4!: string
}

type FilterProperties<T, TFieldType> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends TFieldType ? K : never]: T[K]
}

type B = FilterProperties<Test, Date>
/*
type B = {
    value1: Date;
    value3: Date;
}
*/
```

Comment: How to create an object that is an instance of `FilterProperties<T, TFieldType>`?