# Typescript: How to filter an interface to create a type with only matching pops

Tags: typescript

Given a interface like

```js
interface paths {
  "/api/user/{id}": {
    get: operations["getUserGET"];
  };
  "/api/user/add": {
    put: operations["addUsingPUT"];
  };
  ...
}
```

How can I create a subtype filtering by http methods (get, put, post, etc)?

the result would be something like:

```js
type getPaths = AwesomeFilter<paths, 'get'>

/* equivalent to: */
interface getPaths {
  "/api/user/{id}": {
    get: operations["getUserGET"];
  };
  /* only gets on the interface */
}
```

Comment: What would the result look like?

Comment: @vera. the same, but filtered. If I choose "get", something like

interface paths {
  "/api/user/{id}": {
    get: operations["getUserGET"];
  };
  ...
}

will add to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below custom type to filter based on the method that is present on a nested property.

```js
type MethodOf<T, M extends 'delete' | 'get' | 'post' | 'put'> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<M, unknown>
    ? Pick<T[K], M>
    : never
}
```

You would use it like so:

```js
interface paths {
  "/api/user/{id}": {
    get: operations["getUserGET"];
  };
  "/api/user/add": {
    put: operations["addUsingPUT"];
  };
  ...
}

type getPaths = MethodOf<paths, 'get'>
//   ^? { "/api/user/{id}": { get: operations["getUserGET"] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use the [Pick utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) for this:

`type getPaths = Pick<paths, 'get'>;`

That said, in your example you seem to be mixing up type definitions and object literals, so it's not overly clear.

Also note that TypeScript conventions recommend starting type names with an upper case letter - e.g. `Paths`, `GetPaths` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PickyByType utility type. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756175

```
type PickByType<T, Value> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Value | undefined ? P : never]: T[P];
};
```

For `'get'` it would be `PickByType<T, {get: unknown}>`

`AwesomeFilter` can now pick all types with the given property.

```
type AwesomeFilter<T, Property extends string> =  PickByType<T, {[P in Property]: unknown}>
```